# How to add TTL for refresh token when using IdentityServer4.Contrib.RedisStore

Tags: c#, .net, redis, identityserver4, stackexchange.redis

I'm using IdentityServer4 and IdentityServer4.Contrib.RedisStore in my application. In startup.cs, I have added the KeyPrefix and config options. All the refresh tokens are stored in Redis with the prefix. But, I'm unable to find a way to add TTL for keys.

My Code:

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
               ...//some code
            })
            .AddOperationalStore(opt =>
             {
               opt.ConfigurationOptions = redisOptions;
               opt.KeyPrefix = "MyAPP";
            });
```

Someone please tell me how to configure TTL value for all the keys.

Some solution to add the TTL value to all the refresh_tokens stored in Redis.

Answer (score 1):

In IdentityServer, the token lifetime is controlled in the client definitions.

See https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/reference/models/client/ for details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This fixed my issue.

Comment: Great! glad my answer helped! Freel free to accept my answer if it answered your question.

Comment: Could you please answer this question too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77605745/access-tokens-and-refresh-tokens-are-generated-even-after-expiry-in-identitiyser

Comment: Think the comment on that question is correct; you have a separate cookie session with IdentityServer,  that can, depending on the client configuration log in the user/client silently, without the current user being involved. Use a tool like Fiddler to better understand the flow of traffic between the browser/client/IdentityServer.