# Access_Tokens and Refresh_Tokens are generated even after expiry in IdentitiyServer4

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, identityserver4, openid

We have a .NET Core application which uses IdentityServer4 for authentication and authorization. We are using azure active directory as IdentityProvider.
We are using Redis for Caching. Access_token lifetime is 1 min, refresh_token lifetime is 2 mins.

```
Config Details:
 "AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime": "120",
 "AccessTokenLifetime": "60",
 "RefreshTokenUsage": "1",
 "RefreshTokenExpiration": "1",
 "AllowedGrantTypes": ["authorization_code"],
 "RequirePkce": "true",
 "RequireClientSecret": "false",
 "AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser": "true",
 "AllowOfflineAccess": "true",
 "RequireConsent": "false",
 "AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken": "true",
```

Problem:

When a user logs in, a new access_token and refresh_token are generated, with lifetimes as 1 min and 2 mins respectively.

After 1 min, access_token gets expired and it requests a new access_token. So, a new access_token is issued and also a new refresh_token is issued. The new refresh_token's lifetime is still the same as old refresh_token.

After 2 mins, both the refresh_token and access_token are expired. (In my redis, I can confirm that refresh_token is expired). But suddenly a new access_token and refresh_token are created and the session do not logout. This cycle continues for many times and after 20-30 mins, the session logs out.

I'm unable to understand how a new access_token and refresh_token are generated without asking for credentials and without a refresh_token.

Comment: we require credentials to get the access token from the identity platform right? And upon we sign into the identity platform, we don't need to sign in again in a period of time because the sign-in status isn't expired in the platform. the sign-in status is different from the access/refresh token. So when the token is expired it might redirect to the identity platform to obtain the new token, if the sign-in status is expired then we need to sign in again with username/password, but if it isn't expired, it would return tokens directly. My assumption.

Comment: Remember me type tokens/values are being used to re-authenticate the user and retrieve the new access/refresh tokens.  Those "remember me" types are not one-time use.  A refresh token is designed for one-time use and would avoid having to re-authenticate by either sending a "remember me" value, or if that has expired re-entering their username/password.   The "remember me" value is not often rotated or even tied to a particular session.

Comment: @TinyWang , Im new to this and did not hear the term sign-in status. Is that a general term or is there any variable with that name. Not user how to check the sign-in status. Could you please help me.

Comment: @pcalkins , It is not "RemeberMe" type token.

Comment: because I don't have Azure AD admin role so I can't test for you, but I trust the document I found could explain your concerns.

Comment: Hey Hi, I was about to comment here. It looks like its all because of session. The session details are stored in cookie in my browser. But how to read the content of a cookie. It is encrypted. How to decrypt it and read it ?

Comment: I don't know about it, in my knowledge, all of them should be used only for auth and we should used it to call ms graph api to get required information

Answer (score 0):

user session is different from access token/refresh token.

First of all, when we want to get access token and refresh token for a user using Azure AD as the identity platform, we need the user to sign in advance. And then we are able to obtain the tokens. We can see [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) for more details. Sign into the identity platform(Azure AD) first, then we get id token + auth code from identity platform, and auth code is used to generate access token from identity platform. When the token is expired but the user session is not expired, we don't need to sign in again but we could get a new access token. When the token is expired while the user session is expired as well, then we need to sign in again to get the token.

Access token is used for accessing protected resources and refresh token is used to refresh the expired access token. They are not used to sign in or play the role of a replacement for the sign-in process. Sign in means we need to provide credentials and it is the pre-requirement for obtaining the access token and refresh token. But both the token and the sign in are managed by the identity platform(Azure AD).

Therefore whether the access/refresh token is expired won't affect the sign in status. Whether the user credential is required(sign in status) depends on the user session. Here's a [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/user-session-management#set-custom-session-timeout-for-individual-environment) from power platform which explained it, power platform also used Azure AD.

> For environments that require different session timeout values,
> administrators can continue to set the session timeout and/or
> inactivity timeout in the System Settings.

We also have a document in Azure AD which guide us to manage the [user sign-in frequency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-session-lifetime).

> Sign-in frequency defines the time period before a user is asked to
> sign in again when attempting to access a resource.